# Class Not Declared?? (C++)

Tags: c++

> ISBN.cpp:8: error: 'ISBN' has not been
>   declared
>
> ISBN.cpp:8: error: ISO C++
>   forbids declaration of 'ISBN' with no
>   type ISBN.cpp: In function 'int
>   ISBN()':
>
> ISBN.cpp:9: error: 'area' was
>   not declared in this scope
>
> ISBN.cpp:10: error: 'publisher' was
>   not declared in this scope
>
> ISBN.cpp:11: error: 'title' was not
>   declared in this scope ISBN.cpp:12:
>   error: 'checkdigit' was not declared
>   in this scope ISBN.cpp:13: error:
>   'isbnStr' was not declared in this
>   scope

Line 8 through 14 are:

```
ISBN::ISBN() {
 area = NULL;
 publisher = NULL;
 title = NULL;
 checkdigit = NULL;
 isbnStr = NULL;
}
```

They are all declared in the header:

```
class ISBNPrefix;
class ISBN
{
private:
 int area;
 int publisher;
 int title;
 char checkdigit;
 char* isbnStr[10];
public:
 ISBN();
...
```

Any ideas as to what could be the issue here? I'm guessing that its something simple I'm missing.

Comment: Could you try and get the formatting sorted out? It's really hard to follow code that's all on one line. Indent all your code by at least 4 space characters and it should all work better.

Comment: Blind guess: Circular header dependencies often cause this problem, as the multiple-include guards cause the second iteration round the circular header include to fail silently.

Comment: You did `#include` the header in ISBN.cpp, right?

Comment: Are you sure you want ten character pointers? `char isbnStr[10];` looks more reasonable to me...

Comment: And `std::string isbnStr;` looks even more reasonable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might seem obvious, but have you double-checked that you actually include the header file in `ISBN.cpp`? Maybe, you have accidentally used the same preprocessor constant as include guard for two headers, causing the file with the declaration of ISBN to be effectively ignored? The snippets you posted look fine to me…

Comment: +1 for "accidentally used the same preprocessor constant" the number of times I have seen that.